# Transferred catkin pkgs to new computer and can't launch

Tags: ros, catkin-make, build-package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS community,

I have mainly been working on my laptop but have recently installed hydro on a desktop with Ubuntu 13.04. I installed ROS desktop-full version and ran the install for MoveIt! I transferred my packages to this desktop with a memory stick and moved them to the catkin_ws that was created there.

After running `catkin_make` I tried to launch the package but I get an error saying that ***"[file] is not a launch file nor is [package] a package"***. I see this [post](http://answers.ros.org/question/145881/transferred-code-to-new-computer-and-catkin_make-not-working/) and tried to delete the build and devel folders and run `caktkin_make` once again but the same error message is produced. The *symptoms* in that post were different than mine though.

I feel like there is something silly that I'm missing here. Any and all help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Jordan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188187/transferred-catkin-pkgs-to-new-computer-and-can%27t-launch/) by [JoSo](https://answers.ros.org/users/18857/joso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2014-07-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sterlingm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2199/sterlingm/) on 2014-07-29**:
Did you source catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash?

**Comment by [JoSo](https://answers.ros.org/users/18857/joso/) on 2014-07-30**:
Amazing! So dumb. I remember doing it when I initially created the workspace but when I deleted the build and devel folders and re-made I must not have. Thanks @sterlingm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
source catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

after `catkin_make`

---

Originally posted by [JoSo](https://answers.ros.org/users/18857/joso/) with karma: 120 on 2014-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1